# Can't get resource titles to show in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

According to [the official docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/resources-array), if I supply an array of JS objects with an `id` and a `title` property, I should see the resources listed. I am using the `ResourceTimelineWeek` view.

Instead, I get this:

[image: title issue]

Notice that my resources appear to exist in the DOM, those Id values match what's being returned from my resource function call to the database (via an API endpoint).

The only thing that is weird is that the `title` shows as `&nbsp;`!

I tried debugging because I thought it might be a problem with the data coming back from the database, but no, the data being returned is fine.

[image: data being returned from database]

I have this function that does the mapping between the stuff that comes back from the database:

```
protected getResources(): ICalendarResourceInput[] {
    this.calendarResources = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.calendarResourceList.length; i++) {
        let calendarResource: RotaTemplateShiftCalendarResource = this.calendarResourceList[i];

        let resource: ICalendarResourceInput = {
            id: String(calendarResource.Id),
            title: calendarResource.Title,
        };

        this.calendarResources.push(resource);
    }

    return this.calendarResources;
}
```

As far as how I'm getting the data, I am using a resource function that gets set on the calendar options, here is the code:

```
let resourceFunction: CalendarResourcesFunc = (args: CalendarResourceArgs, success: CalendarResourceSuccess, failure: CalendarResourceFailure) => {
    if (refreshResources) {
        // re-populate lists
        this.calendarEventList = [];
        this.calendarResourceList = [];
        this.populateCalendarData(new Date("2001-01-01"), new Date("2001-12-31"));
    }
    refreshResources = true;
    this.fetchResourceForCalendar(args, success, failure);
};

options.resourceOrder = "displayOrder" as any;
options.resources = resourceFunction as any;
```

Here's the `populateCalendarData()` func too:

```
protected populateCalendarData(startDate: Date, thresholdDate: Date): void {
    let response: RotaTemplateShiftCalendarResponse = this.getRotaCalendarData(
        startDate,
        thresholdDate,
        RotaCalendarDataType.Staff,
        this.values.ouId);

    this.calendarResourceList = response.Resources;
    this.calendarEventList = response.Events;
}
```

And the `fetchResourcesForCalendar` func:

```
protected fetchResourceForCalendar(args: CalendarResourceArgs, success: CalendarResourceSuccess, failure: CalendarResourceFailure) {
    success(this.getResources());
}

protected getResources(): ICalendarResourceInput[] {
    this.calendarResources = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.calendarResourceList.length; i++) {
        let calendarResource: RotaTemplateShiftCalendarResource = this.calendarResourceList[i];

        let resource: ICalendarResourceInput = {
            id: String(calendarResource.Id),
            title: calendarResource.Title,
        };

        this.calendarResources.push(resource);
    }

    return this.calendarResources;
}
```

I'm not sure what else to try to figure out why this might be happening.

Comment: Maybe put `title` in lower case in your JS object?

Comment: Good suggestion @Marijn, I have a function that does the mapping, so it shouldn't be that. If that was an issue, I would expect the Ids not to show either

Comment: How are you linking the resource data to the calendar? Have you used the browser's dev tools to check the data being fed into fullCalendar? If we had a [mre] of the issue including the front-end JS code, it would no doubt help us to diagnose it more easily. Also what language are you using there for the backend? Please add a tag for it.

Comment: @ADyson how would I go about checking the data being fed to the calendar in dev tools? Can you outline some steps on how I can check that?

Comment: Well that depends how you're loading them in precisely. If you're injecting the data into the JS code of the page, check the generated page source (Ctrl+U in most browsers). If you're loading it via AJAX, use the Network tool to examine the raw response from that call. Just the usual JS/browser debugging techniques, really.

Comment: @ADyson I've just added the code to my resource loading function. My data does come back, plus I can see the Ids in the DOM too.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be JavaScript...what exactly are you using? Also, that doesn't show us fully....what does fetchResourceForCalendar do? How does it put them into the actual calendar? We still don't have a [mre] of the issue. No-one can even begin to think of running this, we can't even piece together the disparate bits and hope to understand, end-to-end, how the data gets from the data store into the calendar (and therefore be able to spot anywhere that the process might potentially start to go wrong).

Comment: I understand it is tough to figure it out. The code is TypeScript. I'll try to come up with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Ok thanks. You do seem to have made the process very complicated, by the looks of it! When you edit it, please add the typescript tag too then it's clear for everyone (and people with specialist typescript knowledge may also see the question and be able to get involved). If server-side code is also posted, tag the language of that too. Thanks.